# using usort on array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, usort

I have the below example array:

```
  Array
(
    [0] = Array
        (
            [Campaign] = Array
                (
                    ...
                    [views] = 10
                )
        )

    [1] = Array
        (
            [Campaign] = Array
                (
                    ...
                    [views] = 0
                )
        )

    [2] = Array
        (
            [Campaign] = Array
                (
                    ...
                    [views] = 1
                )

        )

    ...

)
```

I want to be able to sort the array by the 'views' option, so i have written the below:

```
class DashboardController {
...
    public function recruitment_index(){
        ...
        usort($mostviewed, array('DashboardController','sort_objects_by_views'));


        ...
    }

    ...
    function sort_objects_by_views($a, $b) {
        if($a->Campaign->views == $b->Campaign->views){ return 0 ; }
        return ($a->Campaign->views < $b->Campaign->views) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

However i get the below error:

```
Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [APP/Controller/DashboardController.php, line 60]
```

line 60 is `if($a->Campaign->views == $b->Campaign->views){ return 0 ; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already said, that your data is an array. So you should access it the right way:

```
class DashboardController {
...
    public function recruitment_index(){
        ...
        usort($mostviewed, array('DashboardController','sort_objects_by_views'));


        ...
    }

    ...
    function sort_objects_by_views($a, $b) {
        if($a['Campaign']['views'] == $b['Campaign']['views']){ return 0 ; }
        return ($a['Campaign']['views'] < $b['Campaign']['views']) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```